# Flutter Web listen to Events posted through iFrame

Tags: flutter, iframe, local-storage, flutter-web, postmessage

my goal is to **integrate a flutter widget** with the help of an **iframe** on my main page. The main page is not written in flutter. However, I need an interface through which the main page can **communicate with the widget**. So I thought of using *postMessage()* on the main page and *html.window.addEventListener()* in the flutter widget. Now I am receiving an event inside flutter, but cannot see its content. My temporarily solution is to save the message in local storage and only use the listener as a notifier, but i don't really like this approach. Has anyone a better solution for my problem?

[image: iFrame Test]

**Flutter Test Widget:**

```
// ignore: avoid_web_libraries_in_flutter
import 'dart:html' as html;
import 'package:simple_cookies/simple_cookies.dart';


 class MessageListener extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MessageListenerState createState() => _MessageListenerState();
  }

class _MessageListenerState extends State<MessageListener> {
  String last;

  @override
  void initState() {
    html.window.addEventListener('message', listen, true);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    html.window.removeEventListener('message', listen, true);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void listen(html.Event event) {
    last = Cookies.get('iframe_message') ?? 'Error';
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('iFrame Test'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(child: Text(last ?? 'No messages yet')),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**main page:**

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>website title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function pageProcessing() {
            let messageButton = window.document.getElementById("post_message");
            messageButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
                let message = window.document.getElementById("message_text").value;
                window.localStorage.setItem("iframe_message", message);
                document.getElementById('flutter_widget').contentWindow.postMessage(
                    {
                        sender: "main_page",
                        message: message
                    },
                    "*"
                );
            });
        }
        window.document.addEventListener('readystatechange', () => {
            if (window.document.readyState == 'complete') {
                pageProcessing();
            }
        }
        );
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="message_text">&nbsp;<input type="button" id="post_message" value="Send Message">
    </div>
    <iframe id="flutter_widget" src="http://testing.orcaf#####"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To read message data from listener you have to cast event to `MessageEvent`:

```dart
  void listen(html.Event event) {
    var data = (event as html.MessageEvent).data;
    print(data['sender']);
    print(data['message']);
    setState(() {
      //...
    });
  }
```