# Can't modify widget state from window EventListener

Tags: flutter

**Update - Resolved**

Somehow, this problem was happening due to toggling the visibility of the iFrame `div` on the parent website side of things, rather than any `EventListener`/`State` issue on the Flutter slide.

---

I'm following [Flutter Web listen to Events posted through iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66062315/flutter-web-listen-to-events-posted-through-iframe) and trying to send a message from a parent website to a child Flutter app in an iFrame.

The message is working correctly and I can print the value inside the Flutter app; however, I can't call `setState` from my event listener successfully and use the message value elsewhere.

The website code is the same as in the link above. In my Flutter app:

```
class HomePageWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePageWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageWidgetState createState() => _HomePageWidgetState();
}

class _HomePageWidgetState extends State<HomePageWidget> {
  String? messageValue;

  @override
  void initState() {
    html.window.addEventListener('message', listen, true);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    html.window.removeEventListener('message', listen, true);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void listen(html.Event event) {
    var data = (event as html.MessageEvent).data;
    final received = data['message'];

    // This works successfully.
    print(received);

    // This does not.
    setState(() {
      messageValue = received;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(messageValue ?? 'no message');
  }
}
```

I've verified that I'm receiving the message in my `listen()` method. I'm expecting to be able to call `setState` from my `listen()` method too; is there an issue with state scope this since it's being called from the stateful widget's `init` method?

Comment: setState(() {
      messageValue = received;
      print(messageValue);
    });
can you run this for me? does this show anything?

Comment: That prints the message value.

If I create another method, `modifyMessage() => setState() { messageValue = 'hello'; });`, and call that from somewhere else, I get the expected state update and the UI rebuild.

Comment: do this 

    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          setState(() {
            messageValue = received;
          });
        });
don't forget to import `import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';`
tell me if it does not work

Comment: No luck there; as a side note, nothing inside `addPostFrameCallback((_) { ...` is called at all.

Comment: just try  messageValue = received outside of setState() and try empty setState(() {}) to update UI. See if it works?

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work; the UI does not update. The value of `messageValue` doesn't get updated outside of the `listen` callback.

I've tried a couple of other things, like moving the `addEventListener` to the build method, or having the callback modify a variable that has been passed into the widget rather than a property of the stateful widget itself, but I get the same issue.

Comment: @ECS, try this and let me know...Future(()=> {
      setState((){
        messageValue = received;
      })
    });

Comment: I think it's updating the messageValue, but not re-rendering ui. Try the code from my previous comment.

Comment: Same problem. After adding some breakpoints, I can add that the `listen` method calls, updates the `messageValue` value, and `build()` is called, but it does not use the new value of `messageValue`. If I change the message to be an incremental counter that increases when 1) a new message is received, or 2) when a button in the UI is tapped, the state for the `listen` counter and the state for the button tap counter is maintained, but as two different values. And only the button tap callback updates the UI. Really odd!

Comment: Can you post the minimal code for the index.html file, that can reproduce this issue.?
It will help a lot.

Comment: That's helpful - I created https://gist.github.com/eilzo/f9e22ae9dbbec8d7e46cf6550116016f as a light demo, and it works! So I need to work out how it's different to my app's setup.

Comment: Okay, solved! 

In my `index.html`, I had a button which, when tapped, called `customElements.define("flutter-app", FlutterApp);` and created the Flutter app div. If I remove that, and just have the Flutter app iFrame load from the start, it works...

Very bizarre, considering that the iFrame app was receiving messages and able to log the values from it, but couldn't update its own internal state.

Comment: @ECS, I am glad it's resolved. Congrats. :)